# Optimal way to split string into number

Tags: c#, string, expression

I've a string in following format
XXXXYYYZZ
Here XXXX, YYY && ZZ are numbers.
I want to get XXXX, YYY and ZZ From the string. I was using sub string to find it.

Is it the best way, or is there any other optimal way.

Comment: You could use a simple regex and pull matched groups: https://regex101.com/delete/TnWYk83TGmDvJmKcZB74IWx8

Comment: If the length of each sub string is fixed, using `Substring` is probably the optimal method. Using a Regex will quite surely be slower. BTW, "optimal" means "the best", so there is no "other optimal" (or "more optimal").

Comment: Try :            string input = "123456789";
            string x = input.Substring(0, 4);
            string y = input.Substring(4, 3);
            string z = input.Substring(7, 2);

Comment: Would `Span<char>` help? I don't have any experience with it, but isn't it better at this kind of thing?

Comment: @jdweng,  This part I'm already trying, Just wanted to confirm if that was the best option we have.

Comment: @Flydog57 You're right, `Span` is better than `Substring`, the analyzer also suggests to use `Span`.

Comment: "best way" wants opinion-based answers => off-tiopic here

Comment: Regex is much less efficient that string methods.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the string is fixed. you can use Substring():

```
string input = "123456789";
string x = input.Substring(0, 4); 
string y = input.Substring(4, 3); 
string z = input.Substring(7, 2);
```

If you want the `result as a number`, working with `int will be more optimal`:

```
int intInput = int.Parse(input);
var xInt = intInput / 100000;
var yInt = intInput % 100000 / 100;
var zInt = intInput % 100;
```